# OpenMP and GMP Bottleneck Issue

Tags: c++, c, openmp, openmpi, gmp

I have been testing the bottleneck issue of OpenMP and GMP together. I have found some interesting data.

My code is as follows,

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<gmp.h>
#include<omp.h>

void test_fun()
{
    mpz_t x;
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_set_ui(x,2);
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_set_ui(x,2);
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_set_ui(x,2);
    mpz_clear(x);
    mpz_init(x);
    mpz_set_ui(x,2);
    mpz_clear(x);
}
int main()
{
    long i;
    double time = omp_get_wtime();
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(i=0;i<100000000;i++)
    {
        test_fun();
    }
    time = omp_get_wtime() - time;
    printf("Time Taken %lf\n", time);
    return 1;
}
```

This takes 1.755720 seconds in my quad core i5 processor spawning 4 threads. Now, if I iterate the loop for 25000000 (1/4 th) times, with a single core (no openmp), it takes, 1.555573 seconds. So, surely there is a overhead of using GMP for multiple threads. Can anyone point out the main reason.

N.B. There can be a reason that each mpz_init makes a malloc call internally. As malloc is atomic between all the threads, it might create such a time-gap. Or is there any other reason ?

Comment: Just a guess: the memory bandwidth shared across the threads...

Comment: You need data points for several more iteration counts before it it makes sense to try to interpret them, and it would be best to measure each point multiple times to get an average time.

Comment: That's not that big an overhead. Did you try doing just allocations and deallocations in your loop (no GMP)?

Comment: @JohnBollinger Actually, the time I have mentioned are average of multiple attempts and the difference is constant. Basically, when the job size is quite large, say for example time is in the scale of months then there are significant difference (several days or months) between two of such scenarios. This small test is performed after facing such difference in larger scale.

Comment: @MarcGlisse Yes, if you replace the GMP segment with simple malloc and free operations it will show such a difference may be in higher scale. I have also tested that. The overhead amplifies significantly when the job size is large.

Comment: There are many standalone implementations of malloc available, you could experiment with them and see if one is better suited to your use case. The default one is a compromise for many use cases which is optimal for none.